# Spatial Averaging in Matlab

Tags: matlab, average, spatial

I would like to perform a integral averaging on my discrete velocity data U,  [image: The averaging formula along one dimension]

U is a one dimensional array, each value is corresponding to a spatial value of phi.

```
   U(phi) =[15 20 30 74 89 25 78 75 72 56 15]  
            0              pi             2pi
```

U(theta + phi ) is nothing but rotating the array U(phi) by a value of theta which also varies from (0 to 2pi)

```
 if (theta = pi)  % example % 
 U(theta+phi) = [25 78 75 56 15 15 20 30 74 89]  % Matrix is shifted by pi
```

My question is how do I integrate these two matrix, as of now I applied this method(below) but I am not sure if it is correct:

```
U = [15 20 30 74 89 25 78 75 72 56 15];
L = 0:(2*pi)/10:2*pi;
C1 = U;

for lt = 1:1:length(L)

                    if (lt > 1)

                           rt = lt -1;
                           C1 = circshift(U , [1 -rt]);

                    end

             Cm(lt) = 1/(2*pi) * trapz(C1.*U,L);


end
```

Could anyone verify this for me, or give me some other suggestions if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of what you want to integrate you shoud do

```
Cm(lt) = 1/(2*pi) * trapz(L,C1.*U);
```

because if you look at help `trapz`:

`Q = trapz(X,Y)` integrates `Y` with spacing increment `X`. [..] `length(X)` must be equal to the size of this dimension

Answer (score 0):

This Method for (1 Dimension) spatial Averaging works very well

```
  U = [15 20 30 74 89 25 78 75 72 56 15];
  L = 0:(2*pi)/10:2*pi;
  C1 = U;

      for lt = 1:1:length(L)

                  if (lt > 1)
                       rt = lt -1;
                       C1 = circshift(U , [1 -rt]); % Shifts the matrix 
                end

         Cm(lt) = 1/(2*pi) * trapz(L,C1.*U);   % Integration over the data
```

end

Comment: As you are basically saying: *yoh.lej's answer is what I am looking for*: Please delete this answer and accept his answer by clicking the grey check mark next to his answer to [turn it green instead!!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)